# Plotting multiple plots with geom_violing and lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to use lapply to make multiple violin plots, stacked side by side.

The base code is:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = cyl, fill = class)) + 
geom_violin() + ggtitle("cyl") +
geom_jitter(shape=16,position=position_jitter(0.1)
```

So I'm trying to use lapply:

```
plots_list = lapply(
    names(mpg[,3:5]), 
    function(n) 
    ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = n, fill = class)) + 
    geom_violin() + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.1))          
    + ggtitle(n)
)
plots_list[[1]]
```

But `y = n` gives no violin plot.

If I use:

```
plots_list = lapply(
     mpg[,3:5], 
     function(n) 
     ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = n, fill = class)) + 
     geom_violin() + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.1))  + ggtitle(n)
)
plots_list[[1]]
```

Then the plots titles are not correct.

Also, when using:

```
 grid.arrange(plots_list[1:3], ncol = 2)
```

I get errors, but ploting with:

```
 plots_list[1:3]
```

works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Your `n` is not a symbol, it's a string, so you need `aes_string`:

```r
plots_list = lapply(
    names(mpg[,3:5]), 
    function(n) 
    ggplot(mpg, aes_string(x = "class", y = n, fill = "class")) + 
    geom_violin() + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.1))          
    + ggtitle(n)
)
plots_list[[1]]
```

[image: ggplot with violins and jittered dots]

Comment: Do note: the life cycle of `aes_string` and its siblings are [soft-deprecated](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) for tidy eval idioms.